# Jquery clone with true does not clone custom events

Tags: jquery, jquery-trigger

I am cloning a select element which trigger a custom event "combobox".

when I clone the select element, custom events are not cloned.

```
<select id="country">
    <option value="Australia">Australia</otpion>
    <option value="China">China</otpion>
    <option value="Russia">Russia</otpion>
</select>

$('#country').change(function() {
         $(this).trigger($.Event('combochange'));
});     
$('#country').bind('combochange',function() {
         alert($(this).val());
          var clone = $(this).clone(true);
          clone.appendTo('body');
          clone.change();
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/S5RFg/3/)

Comment: you should provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue

Comment: I have edited the question. I know that select clone true doesnot clone the status, But what about the custom events

Comment: `clone.appendTO` ??? Fix that and it should work

Comment: Oh! I made a mistake. I change it to appendTo

Comment: But then what is your issue??? EDIT: i see your are cloning element but not changing ID, IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: It does not somehow work in my system. Custom Event is not triggered when I clone the select

Comment: It should but like i said, IDs must be unique. Check your jsFiddle, you should see that custom event for cloned elements works as expected